# Как реализовать в AppAsset сброс кэша при изменении JS/CSS файла в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

**Проблема**: При измении CSS/JS, чтобы принудить браузер пользователя сбросить кэш, вручную в AppAsset (наследник: \yii\web\AssetBundle) изменяем ?v=*.

[image: Пример ручного изменения версий]

**Вопрос**: Есть ли пути из коробки или другие решения для автоматизации этого процесса? Пока есть только идея: запускать консольный скрипт, который на основе файла CSS/JS делать хэш и он будет прописываться в версию.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-assets#cache-busting  --- про простановку версии.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  Думал оно сработает только для опубликованных ресурсов, т.е. /assets/1124a31a/css. Но сработало и в моем случае! Спасибо!